# Как подключть opencv в QtCreator на Linux Mint

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, linux-mint

Я установиk библиотеку opencv по инсnрукции отсюда http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/, она успешно скомпилировалась. После этого я выполнил команды make install и ldconfid. Иными слоами, все шаги сделал по инструкции, но когда я пытаюсь использовать команды pkg-config, мне выдает вот такую вот ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Из этого следаует, что я не могу узнать пути с помощью команд pkg-config --cflags opencv и pkg-config --libs opecv.

путь к папкам opencv и opencv_contrlib вот такой /opt/opencv и /opt/opencv_contrib, исходя из этого, что мне нужно написать в PRO файле, чтоб начать использовать opencv? Или сделать, чтоб команды заработали

Comment: @AlexF, это не сработало

Comment: @AlexF, может стоит добавить какой то конкретный путь, а не указанный в ответе по ссылке

Comment: @AlexF, в какой строчке ?

Comment: а в репозитарии нет что-ли готовой? или готовая чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: @PavelGridin, не нашел, как скачать из репозитория для плюсов, нашел только python-opencv, или это тоже подойдет?

Comment: я не знаю, как для mint, но для ubuntu `sudo apt install libopencv-dev`